# Finding Windows Live Mail Data

Tags: windows-live-mail

My windows computer crashed but I was able to save all my data on a cloud based service.  I used Windows Live Mail on the crashed computer.  I now have an Apple Mac.  As I search through all my backup data, how do I identify my windows live emails and contacts?  If I am able to successfully find the emails and contacts is there any way to export this data into my new Mac Mail account or at least be able to read the information for later replication when populating Mac Mail?

Comment: Fairly sure in more recent editions of W10, the contacts are synchronized with the (soon to be discontinued?) People app which stores them on the [cloud](http://outlook.live.com/people/), Running that app here produces a "Let's get started" start page, where my current Live account is noted, and attempting to import contacts into that account comes up with something to the effect of already been done. Except for the WLM storage folders, WLM emails from all accounts appear to be used by the Windows Mail app, and the emails all sync to their respective POP/IMAP servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works for Mac, but for Windows, if you want retrieve your stored Live Mail stuff, you head to C:\Users\LOGON\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Mail, with LOGON being the name of the Windows user account.

The difficulty could be however that some files can be hidden, so you may need to display hidden files on the Mac. This link explains how you do that:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-3520878/

For further ideas, you can try these links:

Here for a similar topic in Windows forums that might yield some clues:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/livemail-email/how-to-recover-lost-storage-folders-in-windows/6fa3abe2-865a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1

Here for Windows users with a more detailed version of what I explained above:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/189238/win_live_mail_store.html

Here for Windows users looking to transfer LM info and settings from a corrupted profile:
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/recover-windows-mail-data-and-settings-from-corrupted-user-profile/

There is also an assistant which transfers Windows LM to Mac: 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204087

Hope it helps, good luck!